# Proper use of RequireJS, Coffeescript and Revealing Module Pattern

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, requirejs, amd, revealing-module-pattern

I have defined the following piece of Coffeescript code below, which defines a function using RequireJS:

```
define 'PersonService', ['jquery'] ($) -> 
    getPerson = (id) -> 
        person = dataService.GetPerson id
    { getPerson: getPerson}
```

It produces the following:

```
(function() {

  define('PersonService', ['jquery'](function($) {
    var getPerson;
    getPerson = function(id) {
      var person;
      return person = dataService.GetPerson(id);
    };
    return {
      getPerson: getPerson
    };
  }));

}).call(this);
```

I guess the issue I have is with the self-executing function that is produced from the Coffeescript code. Will this cause issues that I am possibly not tracking? Or is this proper.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's correct

The difference between not having a wrapped function and having one is to do with scope.

If you define var a = 10; in the global scope a becomes global with or without the `var` keyword.

When wrapped all variables are local to the wrapped function so do not end up global.

In you example everything is already wrapped in a function so yes you don't need the extra wrapping!

You can tell coffee-script not to add the wrapper function using

```
coffee -b, --bare         compile without a top-level function wrapper
```

IMHO: It's better to always have the wrapper function so you don't need to think about it on a file to file basis.